# Node.js and passport-facebook callback never ends

Tags: node.js, passport.js

can anyone help me with this issue? the callback never ends. I have followed passport facebook guide and passport-facebook guide and both have the same problem.
Here is my code:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id },{name:profile.displayName}, 
    function (err,  user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/error',
                                      successRedirect: '/success' }));
```

Configuration and dependencies

node.js version 0.10

"express": "3.2.1",

"passport": "0.1.16",

"passport-facebook": "0.1.5",

"paypal-ipn": "1.0.1",

"ejs": "0.8.3",

"sequelize": "1.7.0-alpha1",

"winston": "0.7.1",

"mysql": "2.0.0-alpha8"

Answer (score 2):

Sequelize methods like `findOrCreate()` don't accept a callback function to handle results, but return [a promise-like object](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#misc-asynchronicity):

```
User.findOrCreate(
  { facebookId : profile.id },
  { name       : profile.displayName}
).success(function(user) { // called when findOrCreate was successful
  done(null, user);
}).error(function(err) {   // called when findOrCreate failed
  done(err);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `complete` or `done` as a shortcut (they use the same `err, result` signature as the Strategy's `done` method, so you can pass that in directly):

```
User.findOrCreate(
  { facebookId : profile.id },
  { name       : profile.displayName}
).complete(done);
// or
User.findOrCreate(
  { facebookId : profile.id },
  { name       : profile.displayName}
).done(done);
```

In your case, the callback you provide to `findOrCreate()` is never called and the `done()` function of the Strategy callback is never called.